# Ignore spaces when use array as function parameter in bash script

Tags: arrays, bash

There are two problems.
One of them I expect 5 elements, But array store 15 elements as space.

Here is my code,

**./example.sh**

```
pick_random_data()
{
    # seed random generator
    RANDOM=$$$(date +%s)

    #take array as parameter
    declare -a argArr=("${!1}")

    # pick a random entry from the domain list to check against
    randomResult=${argArr[$RANDOM % ${#argArr[@]}]}
    echo "$randomResult"
}



request_url[0]="POST /playready_license HTTP/1.0"
request_url[1]="POST /fairplay_license HTTP/1.0"
request_url[2]="POST /fairplay_license HTTP/1.1"
request_url[3]="POST /widevine_license HTTP/1.1"
request_url[4]="POST /playready_license HTTP/1.1"


counter=1
while [ "$counter" -le 3 ] 
do
    ran_req_url=$(pick_random_data request_url[@])
    printf "{\"request_url\":\"%s\"}\n" $ran_req_url
    ((counter++))
done
```

**bash example.sh**

```
{"request_url":"POST"}
{"request_url":"/fairplay_license"}
{"request_url":"HTTP/1.1"}
{"request_url":"POST"}
{"request_url":"/fairplay_license"}
{"request_url":"HTTP/1.1"}
{"request_url":"POST"}
{"request_url":"/fairplay_license"}
{"request_url":"HTTP/1.1"}
```

But I wanna print like this

```
{"request_url":"POST /playready_license HTTP/1.0"}
{"request_url":"POST /playready_license HTTP/1.0"}
{"request_url":"POST /playready_license HTTP/1.0"}
```

And another problem is **pick_random_data()** function doesn't work.

And I tried another array form like

```
local request_url=(
    POST\ /playready_license\ HTTP/1.0
    POST\ /fairplay_license\ HTTP/1.0
    POST\ /fairplay_license\ HTTP/1.1
    POST\ /widevine_license\ HTTP/1.1
    POST\ /playready_license\ HTTP/1.1
    )
```

and this

```
local request_url=(
    "POST /playready_license HTTP/1.0"
    "POST /fairplay_license HTTP/1.0"
    "POST /fairplay_license HTTP/1.1"
    "POST /widevine_license HTTP/1.1"
    "POST /playready_license HTTP/1.1"
    )
```

These are still not working.

I refer random function in here.

> https://www.christianroessler.net/tech/2015/bash-array-random-element.html

Comment: Don't seed the each time you're asking for a random number! you completely lose the point of a PRNG! remove the line `RANDOM=$$$(date +%s)`, you don't really need it.

Comment: Re. line breaks, USE MORE QUOTES: `printf "{\"request_url\":\"%s\"}\n" "$ran_req_url"` (see the quotes for the expansion of `$ran_req_url`?)

Comment: In `ran_req_url=$(pick_random_data request_url[@])`, remove the `[@]`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

pick_random_data()
{
    #take array as parameter
    declare -a argArr=("${!1}")

    # pick a random entry from the domain list to check against
    randomResult=${argArr[$RANDOM % ${#argArr[@]}]}
    echo "$randomResult"
}



request_url[0]="POST /playready_license HTTP/1.0"
request_url[1]="POST /fairplay_license HTTP/1.0"
request_url[2]="POST /fairplay_license HTTP/1.1"
request_url[3]="POST /widevine_license HTTP/1.1"
request_url[4]="POST /playready_license HTTP/1.1"


counter=1
while [ "$counter" -le 3 ] 
do
    ran_req_url=$(pick_random_data request_url[@])
    printf "{\"request_url\":\"$ran_req_url\"}\n"
    ((counter++))
done
```

First, you must place `$ran_req_url` inside of `printf`.
Second, use `mRANDOM=$RANDOM$(date +%s)` instead of `RANDOM=$$$(date +%s)` or just `$RANDOM`. It is global variable and it's already randomly.

In your solution, script execute too fast and you have the same value of your `$RANDOM` variable every time: just add `echo "It is my not randomly RANDOM: $RANDOM"` right after your `RANDOM=$$$(date +%s)` and you will see.

Comment: Cool, random function working! But print format a little weird in my bash, like this.`{"request_url":""} POST /playready_license HTTP/1.1`

Comment: @YEEN y, edited my solution. Take attention, I've removed random generator. Just use global `$RANDOM` variable. `date +%s` return the same result in each iteration of the loop, so your `$RANDOM % ${#argArr[@]}` operation were returning the same results more times than you need. Just `$RANDOM` is more randomly in your case.

Comment: You mean that I gonna use `randomResult=${argArr[$RANDOM]}` this form?

Comment: @YEEN use your first solution `randomResult=${argArr[$RANDOM % ${#argArr[@]}]}`. But don't assign any value for `RANDOM` variable earlier. (Check, I've removed `RANDOM=$$$(date +%s)` your string from my code.

Answer (score 0):

The error may be on the line

```
ran_req_url=$(pick_random_data request_url[@])
```

`$()` construct is command substitution; to access array elements, use `${}` construct. Another point is that `@` is giving all elements, not only one.

An other point is the printf construct, prefer simpler string concatenation.

Third point is that `$counter` should begin to 0 if you want to access to first element, in bash array indexing is 0 based.

As a result, this should work better:

```
ran_req_url="${pick_random_data request_url[$counter]}"
echo "{\"request_url\":\"$ran_req_url\"}"
```

Comment: Sorry, not working on my bash...But thank you for knowing that.